# SonarLint, SonarScanner Bug (NonNull annotation)

Tags: java, sonarqube, analyzer, sonarlint

i've found bug/issue with SonarLint, SonarScanner, it shows false-positive issue related to NonNull annotation (Java), rule: "squid:S2637", title: "'@NonNull' values should not be set to null" for following code:

```
public class MyObject {
  @NonNull
  public final String text;

  public MyObject(@NonNull final String text) {
    this.text = text; // SonarLint shows issue in this place
  }
}
```

but for following code there is no issue (and i agree with it):

```
public class MyObject {
  private final String text;

  public MyObject(@NonNull final String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  @NonNull
  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }
}
```

With Java Analyzer 4.8.0.9441, i found another issue for following class:

```
   public class DeviceInfo {
      public final long id;
      @NonNull
      public final String model;
      @NonNull
      public final String osVersion;

      public DeviceInfo(@NonNull final String model, @NonNull final String osVersion) {
        this(0, model, osVersion); //ISSUE: In this place Squid reports about uninitialized non-null fields
      }

      public DeviceInfo(final long id, @NonNull final String model, @NonNull final String osVersion) {
        this.id = id;
        this.model = model;
        this.osVersion = osVersion;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please provide the version of your SonarJava analyzer in your question, and provide the fully qualified name of the @NonNull annotation you are using. I cannot reproduce the issue with version 4.8-RC1.

Comment: Note that it would also be useful if you could provide your version of SonarQube, SonarLint, and if you are using SonarLint connected mode.

Comment: NoNull annotation: android.support.annotation.NonNull;  SonarQube Scanner 2.8; SonarLInt Intellij Idea plugin 2.8.0.1735; SonarQube server 6.1

Comment: I Use Android Studio (2.3.1)

Comment: Thanks for providing versions of tools. I still need the version of the SonarJava analyzer to be able to help you.

Comment: O, sorry, we use Java Analyzer 4.6.0.8784. After updating Java Analyzer up to 4.8.0.9441 it seems it doesn't work properly, because it doesn't find issue when i try to assign nullable value parameter to the non-null field of the class (in this case just Android Studio shows issue). Also i've added additional case for Java Analyzer in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first FP you are reporting, in the `MyObject` class is a known bug which have been fixed in SonarJava 4.7 (see [SONARJAVA-1776](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1776)). It is related to fact that fields accessed with `this.` where not correctly recognized by our Symbolic Execution engine. Latest release of SonarJava contains the fix and it is then logical that the issue disappeared after update.

The second FP you are reporting, in `DeviceInfo` class, is related to the following issue [SONARJAVA-2227](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2227). The issue has not been fixed yet, and is currently planned for version **4.10** of the SonarQube SonarJava analyzer.

Comment: Thank you for response, will wait for fix :-)